# How to programmatically add a Panel in Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this is kind of silly question, but how do I add a Panel to my `WinForms` project at runtime.

I wanted a `Panel` to show at startup, but instead, I get nothing
(No error messages were found)

Here is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Panel panel = new Panel();
 panel.Size = new Size(200, 100);
 panel.Location = new Point(20,20);
 this.Controls.Add(panel);
 panel.Show();
}
```

I've tried using `panel.Visibility = true;` but it's not working :(

Comment: panel is the container, no? What do you expect to see without adding something inside the panel?

Comment: just for context i wanted to make a game engine(yes, you heard that right) and i wanted to make a panel when you click a button, but it doesnt work so i tried it when the forms loads and it still doesnt work

Comment: What does it mean 'it doesn't work'? What is the error message. Check below for a working sample.

Comment: wait a sec, will it appear even if there is no controls inside it? and do i need to set its color too?

Comment: If you don't, it is just a container with the same color as your form. Just changing the color is another way of making it "visible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample for it. A panel alone is a container and not a visible component, you should have something in it. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    Form f = new Form();
    f.Show();
    MessageBox.Show("Will add panel");
    Panel p = new Panel { Size = new Size(200, 100), Location = new Point(20, 20) };
    f.Controls.Add(p); // nothing would show
    MessageBox.Show("Panel added. Continue to add something in panel");

    Label l = new Label { Left=10, Top=10, Text="A label inside the panel" };
    p.Controls.Add(l);
}
```

Comment: yup that work, i just need to add color and it will look nice(tho i will replace the label with a picturebox)

Comment: @MervinpaismakesWindows14, whatever you like. Just  setting BackColor different would show it as a rectangular area on form :)